# How can I access the parent index in a nested for loop in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I have the following nested for loop in Swift:

```
for (index,sentenceObject) in enumerate(sentenceObjectsArray) {
    let sentence = sentenceObject as Sentence
    let sentenceIndex = index
    let wordObjectsArray = sentence.words

    for (index,word) in enumerate(wordObjectsRLMArray) {
        println(sentenceIndex) // Here I would like to access the parent
                               // for loop's index.
    }
}
```

How can I access the parent for loop's index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the inner `index` something else, such as `indexInner`. Now the name `index` is not overshadowed and you can refer to it.

```
for (index,sentenceObject) in enumerate(sentenceObjectsArray) {
    let sentence = sentenceObject as Sentence
    let sentenceIndex = index
    let wordObjectsArray = sentence.words

    for (indexInner,word) in enumerate(wordObjectsRLMArray) {
        println(index) 
        // "index" here means the outer loop's "index"
    }
}
```

The rule is very simple: inner scopes can see everything in the outer scope *unless they are overshadowed* by redeclaring the same name in the inner scope. So if you want to be able to see the outer scope name, don't redeclare it in the inner scope.

Comment: And see my Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: @webmagnets Not that there was anything terribly wrong with your original solution! Quite clever, actually.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am not clever enough to know why it was clever.

Comment: Well, having discovered that the outer `index` was not passing down to the inner loop, you tried to give it a synonym that would pass down to the inner loop. And you succeeded! And since `index` is nothing but a number, and you've no intention of mutating it or anything weird like that, your solution works.